# Extrae Cadena de texto de un Spinner

Tags: android-studio, string, edittext, spinner

private void obtenerListas() {

```
    listaMaquinas=new ArrayList<String>();

    listaMaquinas.add("Seleccione Maquina");

    for(int i=0;i<maquinasList.size();i++){
        listaMaquinas.add(maquinasList.get(i).getTipo()+" - "+maquinasList.get(i).getModelo()+" - "+maquinasList.get(i).getMarca());
    }
}
```

maquina = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.maquina);

```
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> lista;

    lista = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,listaMaquinas);

    maquina.setAdapter(lista);

    maquina.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if (position > 0){
                campoMaquina.setText(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());                            
            }
            }
```

*****En este punto al seleccionar el item del spinner el cual hasta ahora va perfecto, al momento de extraer el texto a un edittext solo recupero las primeras 3 letras y nada mas , a ver si alguien me ilumina gracias.

Comment: No veo el error, ¿lo tienes subido a github para poder probarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Para obetener el texto solo debes extraer de la lista que le pasaste a tu adapter la posicion que te llega del spinner:

```
 if (position > 0){
            campoMaquina.setText(listaMaquinas.get(position));                            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que estoy cometiendo un error en esta linea:

listaMaquinas.add(maquinasList.get(i).getTipo()+" - "+maquinasList.get(i).getModelo()+" - "+maquinasList.get(i).getMarca());

Aca ingreso una linea algo extensa al spinner donde junto 3 textos y envio al array que alimenta el spinner , en el mismo spinner se ve completo los tres textos juntos pero al querer extraerlo a un textview solo me copia las 3 primeras letras.

Answer (score -1):

Para extraer el texto de dentro de un spinner deberias ver este tutorial: https://www.google.com/search?q=spinner&rlz=1C1CHBF_esES822ES822&oq=spinner&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j69i61j0l3.799j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8. Un saludo.